# ASP.net(C#): Is it possible to access controls on one webform from another?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, user-controls, web-parts

I am currently building a web app that will become the new data center (intranet website) for my company. I have it hooked into active directory and have a user group set up to allow page editing. I am creating a usercontrol to give our QA manager more editing power so that he can manage the site without me having to re-code anything.

**Here's my issue:**
As I am using a usercontrol as the new edit control; I need to be able to access the controls on whatever page the edit control is being used on. For the life of me I cant figure out how.

Here is a simple example of what I'm trying to do:

```
 WebPartManager wpm = (WebPartManager)WebPartManager.GetCurrentWebPartManager(this.Page);


    TextBox testBox = new TextBox
    {
        ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue,
        ID = "testID",
        Width = 500,
        Height = 200
    };


    GenericWebPart testGWP = wpm.CreateWebPart(testBox);

    wpm.AddWebPart(testGWP, WebPartZone4, 1); //heres where I get my error. WebPartZone4 is a webPartZone in one of my pages.
```

If I run this code on the page that has said WebPartZone the desired effect is achieved so I know the code works. My usercontrol just cant see the WebPartZone on another page. Any help at all would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Is this not due to the fact that each page is contained and you need to post/get the data from another page? I'm pretty sure this is a protections issue outlined [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/1606008.aspx?How+can+I+access+a+webform+control+from+another+external+class+namespace+)

Comment: @CaptainWibble I had already read that post. It is referring to using multiple classes or namespaces in the same webform. I am attempting to have my usercontrol identify controls of another page. I have seen something to this effect done with one usercontrol changing a property of another usercontrol using session state. I was hoping there might be a way to do something similar.

Comment: Well one method is disabling ValidateRequests in the @page and running any access requests asynchronously using an ASHX handler with AJAX given this is on intranet (note this is a method that is used to check script injection).

Comment: You may have just given me an idea. I'll test my theory and post the answer if it works. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah... I had similiar problem when developed websites in ASP.NET Webforms. It's old technology so You probably need old solutions... Try singleton. It's obsolete pattern but still usefull in Webforms, Winforms and old Windows Mobile apps. Try this site for more nformation, understanding, types and samples: [link](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx)

Comment: @MaciejS. I dont really use MVC, but are you saying this isnt an issue in MVC vs webforms?

Comment: What do You mean "MVC vs webforms"? I think You're hiding some important informations. What technology do You use - ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET WebForms? Or it's some mix of both?

Comment: @MaciejS. I'm useing asp.net web application. Not asp.net(MVC).

Comment: If it's standard ASP.NET Webforms app, please see my first comment in this topic. Webforms are old and almost obsolete pattern and their developing style is quite similiar to standard Winforms. Singletons should work for You.

Comment: @MaciejS. I apologize for effectively turning this into a chat but I dont have enough rep to actually chat. I dont understand how singletons would help considering no matter how it would be used, the code still cant see webpartzone4. Thats a control on one of the other webpages. thats why when I try this wpm.AddWebPart(testGWP, WebPartZone4, 1); it redlines WebPartZone4. Is there anyway you could give me a basic example.

Comment: It's quite hard for me to explain how singletons works, because English is not my native language. But there is also other way I think - reference by session. Session works like dictionary, so You can add there anything You want and get access wherever You want just by key. For example: `Session["SiteName"] = YourFullControlWithStateAndValues;` . On another site You can get access to stored object by key: YourControlType yourControl = Session["SiteName"];. I think it's even better than singletons but You have to add separate control to session on every site which uses it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel slightly stupid for how easy this ended up being, but here it is for anyone having the same issue.

Here's the design for a simple user control I used to test this. Its just a button. xD

```
<%@ Control  Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl3.ascx.cs" Inherits="AcmeCompany_DATA_CENTER_v2.WebUserControl3" %>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" OnClick="ButtonCreate_Click" PostBackUrl="~/WebUserControl3.ascx" />
```

heres the code behind for the user control

```
 protected void ButtonCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebPartManager wpm = (WebPartManager)WebPartManager.GetCurrentWebPartManager(this.Page);

        TextBox testBox = new TextBox
        {
            ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue,
            ID = "testID",
            Width = 500,
            Height = 200
        };          

        GenericWebPart testGWP = wpm.CreateWebPart(testBox);

        wpm.AddWebPart(testGWP, wpm.Zones["WebPartZone4"], 1);
    }
```

I was unaware of the Zones class inside of webpartmanager, and I came across it just scrolling through looking for something that may work. Tada.....It's always the little things.

P.S. @Maciej S. Thank you, While you didn't give me the answer, our conversations helped my brain think to look for certain things.

Comment: No problem. :) Glad to hear that I could help even if it wasn't full solution. :)